Is there a way to make a generic statement that complies with GDPR Article 14 2. (f)
My understanding is that many companies attempt to comply with all or most of the "information that must be provided to the data subject" requirements with a single generic Privacy Notice.  A relavent example is the UK government Approval standard:

The privacy notice:

must comply with the legal provisions of Article 12, Article 13, and Article 14 of UK GDPR


Most of this information is generalisable for all data subjects.  However for Article 14 2. (f) this seems harder:


In addition to the information referred to in paragraph 1, the controller shall provide the data subject with the following information necessary to ensure fair and transparent processing in respect of the data subject:

(f) from which source the personal data originate, and if applicable, whether it came from publicly accessible sources;

In the case of large organisations that get data from multiple different sources for different data subjects the answer to the question "Did this bit of personal information come from a public or private data source" is going to be different for different people.  Whether someone is on the open electoral roll is an obvious way this potentially could vary without the data subject making any contractual obligations.
The sorts of organisations I am thinking about are credit reference agencies, insurance companies, "anti-fraud" companies as well as the obvious "big tech".
Is it plausible that large organisations that process diverse data sources can comply with GDPR Article 14 2. (f) with a generic privacy notice?

The general notices about sources of personal data in Art 14 are complemented by the individual Art 15(1)(g) right to get "any available information as to their source" in the context of a data access request.

The requirements of 14 are very different to 15.  14 is not dependant on asking, either you have, are provided it or they are in breach.

Data aggregation and selling information is quite restricted - and most likely illegal, especially for ad reasons. Only some tiny usecases are allowed, e.g. credit scores.

@Trish Presumably even those have to comply with art. 14.
